# PostgreSQL import text file

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I create a PostgreSQL database and table and I want import data to database with text file.

Example of my data:

```
jameson aa
david bb
piter cc
mat dd
rob ee
```

This bash can import files but is very slow for long files:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/ /\',\'/g' file > My_file
while read line; do
psql -d My_db -c "insert into My_table values('$line')"
done < My_file
```

also i read this resolve but this import just firstline in first field & not use delimiter

```
testdb=> \set content '''' `cat my_file.txt` ''''
testdb=> INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (:content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`\copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) command. This command is designed for import data from files.

```
\copy my_table from my_file.txt DELIMITER ' '
```

It is simple, but Postgres is pretty strict - it requires no empty line on the end and exactly one space between fields.

Note: your data are not consistent - first row contains double space between fields.

Back to your example. It must be slow. You do import per one line - for every line you start psql and there transaction. Using pipe and single transaction option should be much faster. With `awk` you can generate SQL script:

```
cat my_file.txt | \
awk -F" " -v  Q="'" '{print "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(" Q$1Q " , " Q$2Q ");" }' | \
psql postgres -1
```

But there is risk of possible missing escaped apostrophes in data (it same safe as your slow solution). `COPY` based solution should be much better and 100% safe. It enforce all necessary escaping internally.

```
testdb=> \set content '''' `cat my_file.txt` ''''
testdb=> INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (:content);
```

This should not work. SQL statements in `psql` doesn't support bulk operations over array (like ODBC). The result of your example is just invalid INSERT command. The session variables are evaluated as strings substitution. You send a statement to server like:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Jameson','aa',
'david','bb',
'pitter','cc'
... )
```

And this is not valid.

Comment: My_file not have  any blank line and were arranged exactly like the sample
duble space is edited
Unfortunately I could I use your code
That's a little more explanation?

Comment: Tnx pavel , Your guidance was a great help.